# postgresql: negative substring length not allowed but no obvious violation in data

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring, string-length, greenplum

I receive the error message ERROR:  negative substring length not allowed when I run the following query in postgresql:

```
select count(*) as name_matches
from table1 x
inner join
(select * from table2 where trim(last_name) <> 'unknown') y
using (id1)
where substring( trim(x.full_name), 1, (length( trim(x.full_name) ) - 2) ) = trim(y.last_name||' '||y.first_name)
```

However, this query returns 0 results:

```
select count(*)
from table1 x 
inner join
(select * from table2 where trim(last_name) <> 'unknown') y
using (id1)
where length( trim(x.full_name) ) < 3
```

Note that all fields are non-null fields.  Any suggestions for what may have been over-looked?  Thanks!

Comment: I can't see an explanation, but you can use `left(trim(x.full_name), -2)`.

Comment: @klin Looks like the second query pulls back trimmed `full_name`s that are < 3 chars and don't have an 'unknown' `last_name` (of which, there are none since it returns 0 results), while the first query attempts to use that information to avoid the `negative substring length error` by filtering out all `last_name = 'unknown'` records (unsuccessfully, thus the question).  The implication - all whitespace-only/empty-string/less-than-3-char `full_name`s are coupled with a `last_name = 'unknown'`. The results of the second query seemingly contradict the error message on the first query.

Comment: @josiah - you're perfectly right, the `where` condition is executed on the whole `table1`. You should give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.full_name` and `x.last_name` in the final `WHERE` clause are executed on the entire table.  The query optimizer may choose to execute that before or after the join.  It would appear that, in this case, it's getting executed before the join happens, so you get an error because your 'UNKNOWN' items which would cause a negative substring length aren't filtered out, yet.

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem!  To fix, I added an additional where clause to the end: length( trim(x.full_name) > 2.

Answer (score 0):

well you can define safe version that behaves like the on in Oracle like this

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dca_prod.substr_safe(string text, start integer , cnt integer )
    RETURNS varchar
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        if cnt <0 then
           return null;
        else
           return substr(string,start,cnt);
        end if;  
    END;
$function$
;
```

now instead of substr() call substr_safe()
expect that negative count will return NULL

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case an additional WHERE condition would do the trick, if you do a subtr as a column you could make use of the CASE statement and check the length first.